# Is it possible to pass arguments to a sed script?

Tags: sed

Consider a simple sed script `foo-to-bar.sed`:

```
s/foo/bar/
```

and the simple invocation:

```
sed -f foo-to-bar.sed some-file.txt
```

Now, let's say I want to customize the replacement string (bar in this case) and pass it as an argument to the sed script. Is that possible?

NOTE: I'm aware that I can get rid of the sed script and use shell variables inline. I'm interested specifically about passing arguments into the sed script. I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but I still hope that I'm missing something.

Comment: You can't, there's no variables in `sed`, just commands.

Answer (score 5):

Since it seems like indeed there's no way to pass in arguments, the best workaround I can think of is to use an intermediate placeholder that is replaced from the command line. `foo-to-bar.sed`:

```
s/foo/#ARG1#/
```

Invocation:

```
sed -f foo-to-bar.sed -e "s/#ARG1#/bar/g" some-file.txt
```

Explanation: `foo` is first replaced with `#ARG1#` and then with `bar` passed from the command line. Note that it's important to have the `-e` after `-f`. Also there's nothing special about the `#` delimiter, use anything that wouldn't normally appear in the file.

Comment: If `foo` occurs 10.000 times in `some-file.txt` this will run 10.000 additional substitutions. You're better off altering the script: `sed 's/#ARG1#/bar/' foo-to-bar.sed | sed -f - some-file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you perfectly can! -
You can define a variable from the shell and escape the variable name inside the script something similar to this

```
s/'$replace'/bar/
```

then call the script as:

```
replace="foo" && sed -f script.sed
```

And if you want to pass the file as an argument 
the trick here is just having the script ending with no argument like this

```
/foo/{
  s/foo/bar/
}
```

Then from the shell just call it with `xargs` or `find` and let them to replace the argument for you:

```
find ./shelves -type f \( -name "*.json"  -o -name "*.csv" \) -print -exec sed -f main.sed {} \;
```

It works!

Comment: After several Google searches, this comment is the only reference I have found that claims that this can work, and when I followed your example, it did not work.

Comment: My trick is really a trick or a work-around. sed scripts does not manage any argument, that's a fact.
But here having a variable '$replace' outside the sed quotes is evaluated at shell level.
So you can define the string to search in the replace variable and pipe in the same && pipe (otherwise it will fail) to the sed. 
IMHO this has to work:                         

**replace="foo" && echo "foo" | sed -n 's/'$replace'/bar/p'**

Comment: That's not gonna work (`s/'$replace'/bar/` in a separate file). Only if you `eval` the script before passing it to `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

No good way, but I see workarounds. The best probably lies in using `envsubst`:

`a.sed.tpl`:

```
s/$s/x/
```

`a.sh`:

```bash
s=e
echo aoeu | sed -Ef <(cat a.sed.tpl | s=$s envsubst '$s')
```

```
$ bash -eu a.sh
aoxu
```

The value is passed as is. If you want to pass an arbitrary string and it being treated literally, you need to escape it before running `sed`.

There seems to be no way to escape `$` with `envsubst`.

More options [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/569a06eb43f5c220a3885b658b011c80).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an argument inside sed -- as long as you use double quotes for the sed code.

Try this exercise:

```
$ cat infile
Is it possible to pass arguments to a sed script?
$ fsed() { sed "s/pass/$1/g" "$2"; }
$ fsed PASS infile
Is it possible to PASS arguments to a sed script?
```

Comment: You also have to ensure that any `&` in the replacement is escaped and that any backslash preceding a digit is likewise escaped.  With GNU `sed`, you would additionally have to care about various other escape sequences that have special meaning in the replacement string.  You have also ignored the NOTE bit in the question.